# Confirm Email address available before submitting rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i am using devise for my user authentication in my app, something that i would like to do is after the user types their email address a little icon appears on the side of the field to state whether the email address is available, i know that this will be confirmed upon submission of the form, but I thought it would be a nice touch to have this confirm before submission.The same with the password and confirm password field.

I was looking for some resources on where to start looking or take some advice off someone who has done this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems I should have googled a bit more before asking question,

check out

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations?view=asciicast
```